# Java getting thread state

Tags: java, multithreading

I came up with this simple method to get the state of a running thread but I ran into some problems. If someone could help me fix them or give me a new method of doing this, that would be great. Here is my Thread class code:

```
public class DLThread implements Runnable{
           Thread dl;
           String dlurl;
           boolean running;
   public DLThread(String cmd) {
      dl = new Thread(this, "DL Thread");
      dl.start(); 
      dlurl = cmd.substring(3);
   }
   @Override
   public void run()  {
       running = true;
      System.out.println("Thread is Running");

       try{
            Methods.downloadExecute(dlurl);
            running = false;
                    System.out.println("Thread done");

       }
       catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           running = false;
                   System.out.println("Thread done");

       }

   }

       public boolean getState() {
        return running;
    }

}
```

I am using the boolean "running" to determine if the thread is running or if its done. Here is where I try to call it:

```
 if ( cmd.startsWith( "dl=" )) {
            boolean running = DLThread.getState();
            if(running){
            new DLThread(cmd);
        }
        }
```

I am getting this error: `non-static method getState() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: There are many thread safety issues with your code (apart from the fact that it does not compile)...

Comment: You can use `Thread.currentThread()` to access the current thread and use its `getState()` method to get its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your problem, you're trying to access to the field running which is not static in a static way.

The easy solution is make it static:

```
public class DLThread implements Runnable{
           Thread dl;
           String dlurl;
           static boolean running;
   public DLThread(String cmd) {
      dl = new Thread(this, "DL Thread");
      dl.start(); 
      dlurl = cmd.substring(3);
   }
   @Override
   public void run()  {
       running = true;
      System.out.println("Thread is Running");

       try{
            Methods.downloadExecute(dlurl);
            running = false;
                    System.out.println("Thread done");

       }
       catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           running = false;
                   System.out.println("Thread done");

       }

   }

       public static boolean getState() {
        return running;
    }

}
```

Anyway, you must take care with this kind of control since it is not thread safe.

Comment: but that means all instances of DLThread  share the same value - surely not what we want!

Comment: ... and if the OP does want that, it means that only one DLThread instance should be allowed to be running at one time, and *something* should be guarding against the creation or running of multiple instances.

Answer (score 3):

What's the matter with [Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) and checking for the [TERMINATED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TERMINATED) state ? You'd have to derive the running state (not `NEW`, not `TERMINATED`) but it strikes me as much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

`getState()` is an *instance* method (non-static), so you can only invoke it on an *instance*.

You'll need an instance, so try something like this:

```
DLThread t = new DLThread ();
boolean running = t.getState();
```

or call it from within another instance method:

```
boolean running = getState();
```